# Pion custom SFU server not working inside docker

Tags: docker, go, webrtc

I followed this example: https://github.com/pion/example-webrtc-applications/tree/master/sfu-ws

- on local is working
- I made a linux build, I put it on a server, is working
- I put it inside a docker container, it's not working anymore.

On docker I opened the port range:

- 50000-50200:50000-50200/udp

  ```
  version: '3'
  services:
    app:
      image: xxxx
      container_name: web_preprod
      ports:
        - 127.0.0.1:8080:8080
        - 127.0.0.1:6060:6060
        - 50000-50200:50000-50200/udp
      restart: on-failure
      networks:
        - xxxx

    nginx:
      image: nginx:latest
      restart: always
      container_name: nginx_preprod
      command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
     ports:
       - "80:80"
       - "443:443"
       - "6061:6061"
       - "6062:6062"
     networks:
        - xxxx
     volumes:
        - /tmp:/tmp
        - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
        - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
     depends_on:
       - app
     networks:
       xxxx:
         driver: bridge
  ```

port `6061` is not secure, used for testing.

On my server I put the same ports to be used:

```
se := webrtc.SettingEngine{}
se.SetEphemeralUDPPortRange(50000, 50200)
WebRTCApi = webrtc.NewAPI(webrtc.WithMediaEngine(getPublisherMediaEngine()), webrtc.WithSettingEngine(se))
```

But I don't get `onTrack` neither on the server or client.
What I saw, on server I receive

```
PeerConnectionStateFailed
```

I use google stun, and a free turn server on client

```
var config = {
            iceServers: [{
                urls: ["stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302"]
            },
            {
                urls: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca:3478',
                credential: 'xxxx',
                username: 'xxxx@gmail.com'
            }
            ]
        };
        pc = new RTCPeerConnection(config)
```

If you have any ideas I will apreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that Pion (or any WebRTC implementation) is only aware of IP address it is listening on. It can't be aware of all the address that map/forward to it. People will also call this the `Public IP` or `NAT Mapping`.  So when Pion emits it candidates they will probably look like `10.10.0.*` and the remote peer will be unable to contact that.

What you should do is use the SettingEngine and set [SetNat1To1IPs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pion/webrtc/v3#SettingEngine.SetNAT1To1IPs). If you know the public IP of the host it will rewrite the candidates with the public IP.

ICE is a tricky process. To understand it conceptually [WebRTC for the Curious#Networking](https://webrtcforthecurious.com/docs/03-connecting/) may be helpful. Will make sure to answer any follow up questions on SO quickly!

Comment: Shouldn't the STUN server be able to provide the external address?

Comment: Thank you. I had a thought that the server doesn't know his IP, but I lost it.
Thanks, have a nice day!